# How can I provide a 'close reason' for a Flow without using exceptions?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Say I'm producing a finite stream of messages as a `Flow<Message>`. I loop over some source of messages, and, when there are no more messages, break out of the loop to finish the flow normally.

```kotlin
val messages = flow {
    while (source.hasNext()) {
        emit(source.next())
    }
    println("Finished sending all the messages")
}
```

The consumer simply calls `collect` to receive each message in turn until the flow is finished.

```kotlin
messages.collect { doSomethingWith(it) }
println("All the messages have been processed")
```

But what happens when I need to tell the caller *why* the flow stopped? For example, let's say the message producer requires authentication, and I have to deal with token expiry. Now there are two reasons the flow might be terminated, and so my producer looks like this:

```kotlin
val messages = flow {
    while(source.hasNext()) {
        if (authentication.isExpired) {
            break
        }
        emit(source.next())
    }
    println("Finished sending all the messages")
}
```

The problem with this is that the consumer doesn't know why the flow finished. Did the messages simply run out, or do they need to re-authenticate and continue fetching messages? Now, I can think of two possible ways to handle it, neither of which I like.

### Exceptions

An easy solution would be to signal the 'abnormal' flow termination with an exception, like this:

```kotlin
val messages = flow {
    while (source.hasNext()) {
        if (authentication.isExpired) {
            throw AuthenticationExpiredException()
        }
        emit(source.next())
    }
    println("Finished sending all the messages")
}
```

That's great, because now the consumer can use a `try`/`catch` to determine why the flow was terminated:

```kotlin
try {
    messages.collect { doSomethingWith(it) }
    println("There are no more messages")
} catch (e: AuthenticationExpiredException) {
    println("The auth token expired")
}
```

But using exceptions like this is **absolutely not something I want to do**. In his article on [Kotlin and Exceptions](https://medium.com/@elizarov/kotlin-and-exceptions-8062f589d07), Kotlin libraries lead Roman Elizarov explicitly tells us:

> *don’t use exceptions to return a result value, [and] avoid `try`/`catch` in general application code.*

It's a great article and there are many reasons I agree with it, but one critical reason for wanting to not use exceptions is that it introduces behaviour that isn't type checked. If I use my `AuthenticationExpiredException`, then without reading the code, the caller of the flow doesn't know that they have to catch and handle it. The code will compile just fine without the `try`/`catch`, and will fail at runtime. That's an intentional language design choice in Kotlin: exceptions aren't checked at compile time, because they're simply not intended to be used in this way.

### Sealed classes

A great way to return different types of results elsewhere in Kotlin is to use sealed classes. So I might write something like this:

```kotlin
sealed class FlowResult<out T> {
    data class Value<T>(val value: T): FlowResult<T>
    object: NoMoreMessages: FlowResult<Nothing>()
    object: AuthenticationExpired: FlowResult<Nothing>()
}

val messages = flow {
    while(source.hasNext()) {
        if (authentication.isExpired) {
            emit(AuthenticationExpired)
            break
        }
        emit(Value(source.next()))
    }
    emit(NoMoreMessages)
}
```

This is much nicer, because now the two possible close reasons are treated equally. The consumer can use a `when` block to handle the different results, and will get a compilation error if they don't include a branch that handles `AuthenticationExpired`.

The problem I have with this approach is that I can't enforce the rule that the "failure" results must always be the final item in the flow. For example, say I made a mistake and accidentally missed out the `break` from my loop.

```
val messages = flow {
    while(source.hasNext()) {
        if (authentication.isExpired) {
            emit(AuthenticationExpired)
        }
        emit(Value(source.next()))
    }
    emit(NoMoreMessages)
}
```

Now I'll end up emitting the `AuthenticationExpired` value without actually terminating the flow. It'll just continue emitting messages. This could lead to all manner of bugs and security problems, but it will compile just fine.

---

It feels like what I'm really looking for is a mechanism whereby `collect` could *return* a value, like this:

```kotlin
val closeReason = messages.collect { doSomethingWith(it) }
when (closeReason) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve something like that? Or is there another approach that gets around the problems I've described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in method of achieving what you want, but it is possible to build on top of the existing APIs and combine it with the sealed classes:

```kotlin
// Essentially a functional Either type
sealed class Signal<out V, out T> {
    data class Value<V>(val value: V): Signal<V, Nothing>
    data class Terminal<T>(val value: T): Signal<Nothing, T>
}
```

Then build a set of extension methods that do the processing you want

```kotlin
inline suspend fun <reified V, T> Flow<Signal<V,T>>.collect(
    valueCollector: suspend (V) -> Unit
): T = onEach {
    if (it is Signal.Value) {
        valueCollector(it.value)
    }
}.filterIsInstance<Signal.Terminal<T>>().first().value
```

This processed `value` items using the provided collector, and returns the value of the first `Terminal` instance it sees as a return value.